# C++ reading csv replacing commas with zeros

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to write a program to return the amount of rows and columns in a csv file. Below is the code I currently have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("ETF_Corrsv2.csv");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, line)) { // To get the number of lines in the file
            counter++;
            cout << counter;
        }


        //int baz[5][5] = {};
        while (getline(myfile, line, ','))
        {

            int count = 0;
            cout << line;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                if (line[i] == ',')
                    count++;

            cout << count;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

The first part works fine and counter returns the number of rows appropriately. However count does not return the correct amount of commas. When using `cout` to display the lines it shows that the commas seem to have been replaced by zeros however when I open the file with Notepad++ the commas are there. What is going on?

EDIT: Changed code to have all operations in one while loop:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("ETF_Corrsv2.csv");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (getline(myfile, line, ',')) { // To get the number of lines in the file
            counter++;
            cout << counter;
            int count = 0;
            cout << line;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                if (line[i] == ',')
                    count++;
            cout << count;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Still however getting the issue that the commas are replaced by zeros though so count isn't returning the correct number of columns

Comment: Rather than editing the question to ask a new question, why not start a new question. If you do that can you explain where you are seeing zeros instead of commas?

Comment: I'm not asking a new question, the original question of commas being replaced by zeros hasn't been answered. When I use cout << line, instead of commas being there like in Notepad++ there are zeros. for example: 1,2 goes to 102

Comment: Can you provide an example of Your input file and of the output you get?

Comment: OK, so the issue appears to be in this line: while (getline(myfile, line, ','))

Comment: It seems to be replacing the commas with zeros, when I removed the comma ie while (getline(myfile, line)) the function worked

Comment: @Lererferler with ',' getline would read a column at a time so count will always be 0. Remember to add 1 to count as you should have one column more the number of commas.

Comment: Can you give an example of file contents, and using `cout << line` which show s the zeros?

Answer (score 0):

After this loop:

```
while (getline(myfile, line)) { // To get the number of lines in the file
    counter++;
    cout << counter;
}
```

The file has been read totally and no more lines are available. So you have to find another way like storing the file in a string and then count them or do all the work in the first `while` or re open it again.

I think doing all the work in the first loop is the optimal way.

**Possible Solution (not tested):**

```
while (getline(myfile, line)) { // To get the number of lines in the file
    counter++;
    cout << counter;
    int cols_count= 0;
    cout << line;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++){
        if (line[i] == ',')
            cols_count++;
    }
    cout << cols_count;
}
```

Comment: So changed my code above to be very similar to this but I am still getting an issue with the commas being replaced with zeros

Comment: Show us how they are zeros please

Comment: Where are you seeing them as zero? Are you looking at `line` in a debugger? Or what?

Comment: as in when I use cout line, instead of commas being there like in Notepad++ there are zeros. for example: 1,2 goes to 102

Comment: Yes I'm looking at line in a debugger

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you reach the conclusion that the commas have been replaced by zeros?

You read the entire file in the first while loop. Then the 2nd while loop does nothing as it's at the end of file.

Comment: I've been playing around with it for a while. If you take the first while loop out I get the same issue. Opening it in Notepad++ shows commas but in c++ using cout it seems to have replaced them with zeros

Comment: getline discards the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You have read the entire file while counting rows. So there are no data left to read when you get to your next loop where you are counting commas.

I would suggest that you place your comma-counting loop inside your row-counting loop. Or, for a well-formed CSV file, you will have the same number of commas on all lines, so you really only have to examine a single line to find the number of commas.

Answer (score 0):

You have opened the file, and then with

```
  while (getline(myfile, line)) { // To get the number of lines in the file
        counter++;
        cout << counter;
    }
```

read to the end of the file.
Any further reads will "fail".

e.g. When you call

```
while (getline(myfile, line, ','))
{
      //...
}
```

you are beyond the end of the file, so `count` will be zero.

You can use `std::rewind(myfile)` for a FILE* or `std::fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_SET)` for a stream to go back to the start of the file.
You could count the commas as you read the lines.
You could break this into two functions and re-open the file for each count - one for lines and one for comma count.

Comment: You mean `rewind`, I guess, but  maybe, it's better [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) in this case.

Comment: Perhaps - why better in this case @Bob__?

Comment: If you are talking about [`std::rewind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rewind) it seems to me that it is for C streams, while OP is using `ifstream`. Otherwise I'm wrong and I don't know what function are you considering.

Comment: I've also spelled it remind which is rubbish! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet of your code you try to read the file twice without going back to file start. In the second, when you try to count the columns (commas) you use getline with ',' as a delimiter, so your count always restart at every column.

You can try this version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile{"ETF_Corrsv2.csv"};

    if ( myfile.good() )
    {
        int rows = 0;           
        std::string line;

        while ( getline(myfile, line) ) {
            // skip empty lines
            if ( line.empty() )
                continue;
            ++rows;
            cout << "line " << rows;

            int columns = 0;    
            for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                if (line[i] == ',')
                    columns++;
            // if the line is not terminated by a ','
            if  ( line[line.size() - 1] != ',' )
                columns++;

            cout << " has " << columns << " columns: "
                 << line << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This can manage messy input files like:

```
45, 23, 48, 8.15e-8, 18, 21,
1, 4, New york, 18, 20

9, 8, Chicago, 6, 5, Up, Down, 2, 1
```

Outputting:

```
line 1 has 6 columns: 45, 23, 48, 8.15e-8, 18, 21,
line 2 has 5 columns: 1, 4, New york, 18, 20
line 3 has 9 columns: 9, 8, Chicago, 6, 5, Up, Down, 2, 1
```